# Bootstrap tabbed panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to get a "tabbed panel". I've got a panel and a tabbed menu working just fine, but there is a gap between the panel and the tabbed nav.

I'm still trying to figure out this Bootstrap framework, so any guidance would be most appreciated. I've enclosed a screenshot too of what it's appearing like [screenshot of tabbed pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo4Co.png). I've taken out all the PHP code so it's easier to replicate.

**Here's the code:**

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

#exTab1 .tab-content {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

#exTab2 h3 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}


/* remove border radius for the tab */

#exTab1 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}


/* change border radius for the tab , apply corners on top*/

#exTab3 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

#exTab3 .tab-content {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exTab3" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#overview" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Overview</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#assets" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Assets</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Services</strong></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">

    <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">
      <!-- Overview -->
      <!-- Default panel contents -->
      <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-user" center-block style="font-size:inherit;color:orange;"></i> Overview</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Your content here</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /Overview -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="assets">
      <!-- Assets -->
      <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-bug" center-block style="font-size:inherit;color:orange;"></i> Associated Assets</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Your content here</p>
        <!-- Table -->
        <!-- /Assets -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="services">
      <!-- Services -->
      <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" center-block style="font-size:inherit;color:orange;"></i> Associated Services</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Your content here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/richss/mxp8qm2a/20/

**UPDATE**

Dropping the working code into our "portal" the styles etc are being pulled, screenshot:

[image: result]

Comment: Can you kindly correct your code so i can help you

Answer (score 2):

Your code almost works, you just need to add `jQuery` and close assets tab `<div>` before starting the services `<div>`.

See working demo here https://jsfiddle.net/dLpm9hgy/2/

Or here:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

#exTab1 .tab-content {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

#exTab2 h3 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}


/* remove border radius for the tab */

#exTab1 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}


/* change border radius for the tab , apply corners on top*/

#exTab3 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

#exTab3 .tab-content {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="exTab3" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#overview" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Overview</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#assets" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Assets</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Services</strong></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">

    <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">
      <!-- Overview -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-user" center-block style="font-size:inherit;color:orange;"></i> Overview</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /Overview -->

      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tab-pane" id="assets">
      <!-- Assets -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-bug" center-block style="font-size:inherit;color:orange;"></i> Associated Assets</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>

        <!-- Table -->

        <!-- /Assets -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="services">
      <!-- Services -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" center-block style="font-size:inherit;color:orange;"></i> Associated Services</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Below is a list of associated services for user:</th>

            </tr>


            es -->

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="4b">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is making some sense.. almost there but not 100%

If you see the "blue" box behind the panel. I'm sure i'm doing something wrong. I'd like it all to line up and the blue to have a border. 

This should help: https://jsfiddle.net/richss/9jomh897/

Comment: not sure what you mean.... you want to remove the blue?? check this https://jsfiddle.net/dLpm9hgy/7/ and let me know :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm having some issues with bootstrap inter-fearing. The code works standalone. Thats the easy part but when I add it into my wordpress portal template, it's just stripping everything: Here's the example: https://prnt.sc/ieo35u

Comment: oh, wordpress.... hahahaha... not an expert... I prefer to webdevelop from scratch :D.... But anyway.... if you bought a template my advise would be to contact creators they will let you know how to add this part to your site. Otherwise if you're using a free one you can get better advise at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, it's a very complex portal using limitless theme. Very overly, complex. It's the bootstrap.css file, thats stripping everything.

Comment: Hi @richard as you're a new user and you never marked a question as answered I think you must know if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this.